# How to see if Hash Key exists with particular attribute ever in table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table that has both a HashKey and a RangeKey.

The table contains many different messages that are sent to devices.

The HashKey is an ID unique to each device, and the RangeKey is a timestamp of when the message was sent.

One of the attributes on the messages is an INT representing a message type.

What I am trying to find is all the unique device IDs that have a particular message type ever appear in the table.

For example lets say there are 100 devices each with 100 messages; 10 000 total messages. Message type 7 is rare and of those 10 000 only 50 messages are of type 7, and those 50 might have only been sent to 20 different devices.

Is there an easy (and fast) way to get each unique device ID that ever has had a message with type 7?

I know I can scan the table, filter on the message type and then track the unique device IDs that appear in the result. But this has two problems, scanning the whole table is slow and also the same unique device ID will be in the result many times when I only need to know if it ever appears with that message type. (In this example it's not so much of a problem but with 10s of millions of messages I want to avoid checking the same device ID over and over in the scan result)

Is there something I can do with a query that I am not thinking of, or a GSI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a GSI on the integer field that holds the message type as the HashKey and the Device ID as the Range Key. Note that type (HashKey, RangeKey) tuple in a GSI need not be unique.

Then

- To know if a device received a particular message type, you can do a index search by HashKey (MessageType), Range Key (Device ID). 
  Also, note that, depending on the number of records, the results might span across multiple pages and so you should retrieve all the pages to know if a particular device ID ever got a message of a given type.
- To get the list of devices that received a particular message type, you can do a search by HashKey (MessageType). The paging comment above applies here too, to retrieve all unique Device IDs that ever received a message of a given type.